# Import a GitHub library into an existing Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, github, import, project

I have an existing Eclipse Java project and I want to add this library  ([Eclipse plugin for working with Git repositories](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github.git)) to the project.
How can I do that in Eclipse? Is there a menu or something to add a library?

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories).

Sounds like you might want the ***Import Existing Projects*** option on the import wizard (described with screenshot in the link above).

Comment: Not really, I actually want to add a library that helps me use GitHub API in order to be able to download the zip file of a known user's repository. I just want to use the getRepository function (or something like that) to get the url of the zip file to download.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the plugin using the instructions found here: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/download/

Easiest way: With your Eclipse instance open, go to this link: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/egit-git-team-provider  and drag the "Install" button into the instance.